# Best way to use re.sub with a different behavior when first called

Tags: python, function, global-variables, python-re

I'm trying to perform a number of replacements using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub), except I want the first replacement to be different. One straightforward approach would be to run `re.sub()` twice with `count = 1` for the first call, but because `re.sub()` allows for the `repl` argument to be a function, we can do this in a single call:

```
import re

def repl(matchobj):
    global first_sub
    if first_sub:
        first_sub = False
        print(f"Replacing '{matchobj.group()}' at {matchobj.start()} with ':)'")
        return ":)"
    else:
        print(f"Deleting '{matchobj.group()}' at {matchobj.start()}")
        return ""

text = "hello123 world456"
first_sub = True
text = re.sub(r"\d+", repl, text)

# Output:
#   Replacing '123' at 5 with ':)'
#   Deleting '456' at 14
```

Unfortunately, this makes use of `global`, which isn't great. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you actually needs the prints? Or is it enough if the function just returns the proper string?

Comment: Actually this uses *two* globals: `repl` and `first_sub`. Do you mind *both* or just one of them? I.e., would a global helper function be alright?

Comment: @nocomment The prints would be nice for monitoring if the patterns are working as intended! But I can work around that. And regarding globals, in my actual project `repl()` is defined in another function, but I suppose the main thing I was worried about was using the `global` keyword, which I've been told is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an iterator, inspired by Andrej:

```py
import re

text = "hello123 world456"
text = re.sub(
    r"\d+",
    lambda _, i=iter([":)"]): next(i, ""),
    text
)
print(text)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3mzJzC_KLShSKUrm4SlIrShRsFZQyUnNy8g2NjBXK84tyUkxMzZRgUkWpesWlSRpcCkBQpBSToq2kA2bnJOYmpSQqxOsoZNpmlqQWaUQrWWkqxWpaKeQBNWpk6igoKWlClIJM4tLkKijKzCvRAHE0IS6BOgjmMAA)

Or using a dict for the state:

```py
import re

text = "hello123 world456"
text = re.sub(
    r"\d+",
    lambda m, d={0: ":)"}: d.pop(0, ""),
    text
)
print(text)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3GzJzC_KLShSKUrm4SlIrShRsFZQyUnNy8g2NjBXK84tyUkxMzZRgUkWpesWlSRpcCkBQpBSToq2kA2bnJOYmpSQq5OoopNhWG1gpKFlpKtVaKaToFeQXaBjoKCgpaUIUgszh0uQqKMrMK9EAcTQh7oA6B-YsAA)

Or one like yours but with a closure:

```py
import re

def repl():
    first_sub = True
    def repl(matchobj):
        nonlocal first_sub
        if first_sub:
            first_sub = False
            print(f"Replacing '{matchobj.group()}' at {matchobj.start()} with ':)'")
            return ":)"
        else:
            print(f"Deleting '{matchobj.group()}' at {matchobj.start()}")
            return ""
    return repl

text = "hello123 world456"
text = re.sub(r"\d+", repl(), text)
print(text)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZFLTsMwEIbF1qcYeZNYLZV4VSgSO8QBEEsk5CaTxsi1o8lYBSFOwqYbuAtX4DQ4zUtFsGA2tv9_xp898_ZRP3Pl3W73Hrg8vvw6-jSb2hMDoRAFlnGtbaoyATFKQw0_NGEFV3BHAffimLTRnFd-9dgnt-G8sz7XdqocLVNO4lTwk3KjbYMHbk3GcVrK24jUuXFrSF4G8mJNPtSpek1AM0xyw5o4yrA1XEGSqUSqg0sJOZADmSk56hjJ2a_oa7TI_yP_weto_altohCMTxw_Liu01p-cnsHWky3OL5ZysAgXsTkpyftiJuf9gObQukp0b9zvu4n2gx0G_A0)

Comment: I compared the two and it seems the dictionary method is ever so slightly faster, although the difference is a one-time thing and becomes negligible as the number of substitutions increase. As such, I think I'll go with the iterator since it's the most readable.

Comment: @Zachary Yes, I much prefer the iterator one. If you're interested in top speed and are even measuring the performance, I might have something faster...

Comment: @Zachary See the third solution. Might be faster (if you remove the prints).

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to use `itertools` for the task, for example:

```py
import re
from itertools import chain, cycle

text = "hello123 world456 world456 world456"

to_sub = chain([":)"], cycle([""]))

text = re.sub(r"\d+", lambda g: next(to_sub), text)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
hello:) world world world
```

---

OR: If you don't want to use global variable:

```py
text = re.sub(r"\d+", lambda _, i=chain([":)"], cycle([""])): next(i), text)
```

---

EDIT: As @no_comment states in the comment, you can use also `itertools.repeat`:

```py
chain(repeat(":)", 1), repeat(""))
```

Comment: Or `repeat("")`

Comment: Ha, I wouldn't use it for 1 :-)

Comment: @nocomment I like it :) the intention is pretty clear... Yeah, it's few keystrokes more...